# Accepting nominations for a replacement moderator!

Tags: discussion

One of the current moderators, [mafu](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/60/mafu), is going to step down from their position as Pro Tem moderator. As a result, it falls upon the Community Team to pick a replacement for them. However, we decided we'd let users express interest in taking up the position and their peers show their support and/or concerns on each user's nomination, and take that into consideration when making our decision. **Note that the decision will ultimately be made by the Community Team, and votes may or may not be a proxy for who gets chosen — we'll take them into consideration, but this is not an election.**

I believe a week should be enough time, so on Wednesday, May 4th, the nominations will be closed, and we'll analyse the results and reach out to the person who seems like the best fit for us.

---

**Please express your interest in taking up the position if you feel you would make an excellent moderator.**

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to your profile (parent and meta) so we can see your activity.
- Optionally you can write something about yourself, and why you think you'd make a good candidate.

**Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...**

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Answer (score 17):

I would like to nominate myself ([parent profile](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/2537/murgatroid99), [meta profile](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2537/murgatroid99)).

I have participated in community moderation of this site and of Arqade ([main profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1787/murgatroid99), [meta profile](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1787/murgatroid99)) for several years. I am an active participant in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games), and from my experience in the Arqade chat room, I believe that can improve both the speed and quality of site moderation.

I am among the most active users on this site, both on the main site and meta, and I believe that my average question and answer scores speaks to the quality of my contributions to both.

Comment: Not that it's necessarily an issue, but do you have any activity outside Magic? Seems like it's possible to get slightly skewed ideas of scope and such if you're too focused.

Comment: You're right, I have very little activity that's not Magic related. And I'll admit that that is a point against me, but I think that it doesn't take much experience in a tag to moderate it at the level of a diamond moderator handling flags seems to be a generally tag-agnostic activity.

Comment: Yeah, it's not such a big deal in flags as it is in binding close/reopen votes (mods are sometimes helpful to speed things along). No worries, still think you'd be a good mod, just wondering how you see it!

Comment: Yeah, I already have a little experience with binding close votes: I have a gold [tag:magic-the-gathering] badge. So I wait for a number of other people to vote before I cast the binding vote based on how confident I am in the vote, and I think the same strategy would work with binding mod votes.

Comment: Having MTG expertise on the mod team is a huge plus, IMHO.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Definitely agree, probably should've said even more strongly it wasn't an issue. Really just wanted to gauge views, since I know I've seen some meta-concern about MTG's relative dominance on the site.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to nominate myself. ([Parent Profile](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/5001/joe-w), [Meta Profile](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5001/joe-w))

Currently I am active on the site on a daily basis and I am the top all time reviewer in 3 queues, 4th in 2 more and slowing doing more in another.

I also frequently check the meta site and have contributed to that in the past and will continue to do so.

I think overall I can help contribute to the moderation of the site and work in the direction that the community chooses to go.