# New Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some of you may have [read](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1467/12248), one of the current moderators, [mafu](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/60/mafu), is going to step down from their position as Pro Tem moderator. Since we still don't have a prediction for when this site will be fully graduated and able to host its first elections, a replacement for the position left open was in order. Let's all thank mafu for the time and effort they've put into this community!

And I am pleased to announce that murgatroid99 has stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed, and to continue to help the site grow into a huge success.

[image: murgatroid99]

Please welcome murgatroid99 for the hard work and time they contribute.

You can read about the Pro-Tem Moderator program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **there'll be elections once the site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Welcome @murgatroid99!

Comment: Thank you @murgatroid99, best wishes!

Comment: welcome on board @murgatroid99

Comment: Good to have you aboard @murgatroid99. :)